# Extract data from oracle XML type columns

Tags: xml, oracle

This is how the XML within the table looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<select multiselect="false" name="c_f_2441_select_dev" phiField="true" readOnly="false" title="select_dev">
  <dataValidationRule/>
  <CFData>false</CFData>
  <suppressRules>false</suppressRules>
  <options>
    <option code="1" status="A">Sel1</option>
    <option code="2" status="A">Sel2</option>
    <option code="3" status="A">Sel3</option>
  </options>
  <groups/>
</select>
```

Within the "options" element there are three values 'Sel1', 'Sel2' and 'Sel3'

```
select xt.* 
from  ST3_ENT1_REG4.custom_field cf,
      XMLTABLE('/select'
      PASSING cf.data_model_xml
         COLUMNS 
           options   VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'options'
          ) xt
where field_name='c_f_2441_select_dev';
```

The above query concatenates the three values and gives me the output as "Sel1Sel2Sel3". Is there a way I can get those three values in three different row.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c22cd/12)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE custom_field ( field_name, data_model_xml ) AS
SELECT
'c_f_2441_select_dev',
XMLTYPE( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<select multiselect="false" name="c_f_2441_select_dev" phiField="true" readOnly="false" title="select_dev">
  <dataValidationRule/>
  <CFData>false</CFData>
  <suppressRules>false</suppressRules>
  <options>
    <option code="1" status="A">Sel1</option>
    <option code="2" status="A">Sel2</option>
    <option code="3" status="A">Sel3</option>
  </options>
  <groups/>
</select>' ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

If you just want the content of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd option element:

```
select xt.* 
from  custom_field cf,
      XMLTABLE('/select/options'
      PASSING cf.data_model_xml
         COLUMNS 
           option1   VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'option[1]',
           option2   VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'option[2]',
           option3   VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'option[3]'
          ) xt
where field_name='c_f_2441_select_dev'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c22cd/12/0)**:

```
| OPTION1 | OPTION2 | OPTION3 |
|---------|---------|---------|
|    Sel1 |    Sel2 |    Sel3 |
```

**Query 2**:

If you want the text of the option element where the `code` attribute is 1, 2 and 3 then:

```
select xt.* 
from  custom_field cf,
      XMLTABLE('/select/options'
      PASSING cf.data_model_xml
         COLUMNS 
           option1   VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'option[@code=1]',
           option2   VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'option[@code=2]',
           option3   VARCHAR2(20)  PATH 'option[@code=3]'
          ) xt
where field_name='c_f_2441_select_dev'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c22cd/12/1)**:

```
| OPTION1 | OPTION2 | OPTION3 |
|---------|---------|---------|
|    Sel1 |    Sel2 |    Sel3 |
```

**Query 3 - Update - in separate rows.**:

```
select xt.* 
from  custom_field cf,
      XMLTABLE(
        '/select/options/option'
        PASSING cf.data_model_xml
        COLUMNS value VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'text()'
      ) xt
where field_name='c_f_2441_select_dev'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c22cd/12/2)**:

```
| VALUE |
|-------|
|  Sel1 |
|  Sel2 |
|  Sel3 |
```

Comment: I wanted the data to be populated in three different rows but under single column.

Comment: @Mallikarjunasiraguppi Updated